# How to load & deserialize a token account in anchor?

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I want to load & deserialize a token account which is inputted as AccountInfo<'info> into an anchor program

Comment: The data contained within an `AccountInfo` is just raw bytes that can be interpreted in many different ways.  You may want to narrow the scope of the question to something specific that you're trying to deserialize, e.g. a token account, or a mint account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor has a `try_from` method implemented for all anchor accounts and for some special accounts, like the spl token program accounts.

Loading a regular anchor account struct called `OpenOrders` looks like this

```
let mut user_open_orders: Account<OpenOrders> =
                    Account::try_from(user_account_info)?;
```

When trying to load one of the custom structs, you can check the [anchor source](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/698426033052781988cd7980249726501ae08bdc/spl/src/token.rs) for SPL tokens. `TokenAccount` implements the required traits, namely `AccountDeserialize` so `try_from` should also work here. Though I haven't run this code.

```
use anchor_spl::token::TokenAccount;
...
let mut this_token_account: Account<TokenAccount> =
                    Account::try_from(token_account_info)?;
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's how `Account` does it:

```
pub fn try_from(info: &AccountInfo<'a>) -> Result<Account<'a, T>> {
    if info.owner == &system_program::ID && info.lamports() == 0 {
        return Err(ErrorCode::AccountNotInitialized.into());
    }
    if info.owner != &T::owner() {
        return Err(Error::from(ErrorCode::AccountOwnedByWrongProgram)
            .with_pubkeys((*info.owner, T::owner())));
    }
    let mut data: &[u8] = &info.try_borrow_data()?;
    Ok(Account::new(info.clone(), T::try_deserialize(&mut data)?))
}
```

so your implementation might be something like

```
pub fn deserialize<T>(info: &AccountInfo<'a>) -> Result<T> {
    if info.owner == &system_program::ID && info.lamports() == 0 {
        return Err(ErrorCode::AccountNotInitialized.into());
    }
    if info.owner != YOUR_PROGRAM {
        return Err(Error::from(ErrorCode::AccountOwnedByWrongProgram)
            .with_pubkeys((*info.owner, YOUR_PROGRAM)));
    }
    let mut data: &[u8] = &info.try_borrow_data()?;
    Ok(T::try_deserialize(&mut data)?)
}
```

Comment: thanks but how can i do it in anchor. so now I have AccountInfo<'info>. it is `TokenAccount` Account. how can I check the data?

for example:

`token_vault.owner` or `token_mint.decimal`

Comment: `let new_account_info = next_account_info(account_info).unwrap();
  let token_a_vault =  new_account_info.try_borrow_data()?;`

what should i do next?

Comment: It's possible to just call `try_from` directly rather than reimplementing it. I posted a response showing how